# Table format, columns order

Tags: powershell, formatting

I need to decide the columns' orders of my table. My actual command is that one:

```
$tab | Sort-Object "Pourcentage" -Descending |
  Format-Table -AutoSize |
  Out-String -Width 4000 |
  Out-File -Append O:\sigdci\public\parcoursArborescence\bilanAnalyse.txt
```

It gives me that order:

```
Derniere modification   Categorie recherchee   Dernier acces   Dossier   Pourcentage
```

But I need "Dossier" to be first, then "Categorie recherchee" and "Pourcentage" shall be 2nd and 3rd. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Specify the column headers in the desired order:

```
$tab | Sort-Object "Pourcentage" -Descending | 
  Format-Table 'Dossier', 'Categorie recherchee', 'Pourcentage',
               'Derniere modification', 'Dernier acces' -AutoSize |
  Out-String -Width 4000 |
  Out-File -Append 'O:\sigdci\public\parcoursArborescence\bilanAnalyse.txt'
```

If you need to dynamically determine the column names you could do it like this:

```
$headers = $tab[0].PSObject.Properties |
           Where-Object MemberType -eq NoteProperty |
           Select-Object -Expand Name
```

However, you'd have to bring that list into your desired order somehow. Perhaps you could do it like this:

```
$allHeaders    = 'Dossier', 'Categorie recherchee', 'Pourcentage',
                 'Derniere modification', 'Dernier acces'
$actualHeaders = $tab[0].PSObject.Properties |
                 Where-Object { MemberType -eq NoteProperty } |
                 Select-Object -Expand Name
$headers = $allHeaders | Where-Object { $actualHeaders -contains $_ }
```

`$allHeaders` is an array that contains all headers in the correct order. Then you remove all items that aren't present in `$actualHeaders` from that list, preserving the order of the remaining headers.

Comment: Will this work even when one of the columns doesnt exist ? Because the program's user is able to activate some columns only.

Comment: Problem is that when all columns are shown, they are taking too much place. Do you have an idea for not showing the empty ones ?

Comment: +1 for showing how to do this in a more dynamic fashion rather than just hard-coding like all the other examples i have seen! This was really helpful for me